# Report Job difference in HR schema

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to Oracle and try to practice with HR schema. For example I want to report of those whose job is different from the previous job.

Employee name in `employees` table and job history in `job_history` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following query will help. (I am considering that current `JOB_ID` is present in the `EMPLOYEES` table and you want to compare it with the latest previous `JOB_ID` from `JOB_HISTORY` table for the employee)

```
SELECT E.*, JH.LATEST_PREV_JOB_ID 
FROM EMPLOYEES E 
JOIN (SELECT FIRST_VALUE(JH.JOB_ID) OVER (PARTITION BY JH.EMPLOYEE_ID 
                           ORDER BY JH.START_DATE DESC NULLS LAST) AS LATEST_PREV_JOB_ID, 
             JH.EMPLOYEE_ID 
        FROM JOB_HISTORY JH) JH
ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = JH.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE E.JOB_ID <> JH.LATEST_PREV_JOB_ID
```

**----- Update**

You want the query without partition by clause (i.e. without `WINDOWS` function), We can use the `NOT EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT E.*, JH.LATEST_PREV_JOB_ID 
FROM EMPLOYEES E 
JOIN (SELECT JH.JOB_ID AS LATEST_PREV_JOB_ID, 
             JH.EMPLOYEE_ID 
        FROM JOB_HISTORY JH
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM JOB_HISTORY JHIN 
                                  WHERE JHIN.EMPLOYEE_ID = JH.EMPLOYEE_ID 
                                    AND JHIN.START_DATE > JH.START_DATE)) JH
ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = JH.EMPLOYEE_ID
WHERE E.JOB_ID <> JH.LATEST_PREV_JOB_ID
```

Comment: thank for pay attention to my problem,,,can you remove partion by?and write your query without that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right your question, then the answer maybe something like this:

```
select
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    e.job_id as prev_job,
    jh.job_id as last_lob
from
    employees e,
    job_history jh,
    (select
        employee_id,
        max(end_date) as max_end_date
    from
        job_history          
    group by
        employee_id
    ) t    
where
    (jh.employee_id = e.employee_id) and
    (jh.job_id <> e.job_id) and
    (jh.end_date = t.max_end_date) and
    (t.employee_id = jh.employee_id)
```

Comment: that's true but in job history for example neena change jobs two second,i want considered last job in job history